# Convert date and/or time from varchar

Tags: sql, date

How can I convert `varchar` string to `date`?

```
select CONVERT(date,'23/12/2019')
```

avoiding the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server (as suggested by the use of `CONVERT()` for this purpose), you can use [`CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with a third argument to specify DD/MM/YYYY format.  That argument is `'DD/MM/YYYY'`.  No.  Wait.  That would be too sensible.  You want:

```
select CONVERT(date, '23/12/2019', 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right except one thing which is missing from your statement and that is **`date_style similant`**.

```
select CONVERT(date, '23/12/2019', [put the similant here])
```

**Example**

```
select CONVERT(date, '23/12/2019', 110)
```

**Result**

```
2019-12-23
```

for full understanding

### [Click Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)